# multiple legends setting legend key circle color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot:

```
dates = c("2017-03-13","2017-03-13","2017-03-14","2017-03-14","2017-03-14")
value = c(5,6,7,8,9)
group = c("A","B","A","B","C")
size = c(10,20,30,40,50)
data =data.frame(dates= dates, value = value, group = group, size = size)
ggplot(data, aes(x = dates, y = value, group = group)) + geom_point(aes (color = as.factor(group), size= size ))+
 scale_color_manual(name="group",
                     labels = c(A="A",B= "B",C = "C"),
                     values = c(A="green",B="red" , C = "orange" )
  ) + theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black", colour = "black"),
    legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "black")
  )
```

There are 2 issues:

(1) Currently in the Size legend the circle is black and the background is black. How do I make the color of the circle red so that you can see the circles on the black background?

Comment: There are three kinds of people.  Those who can count and those who can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `override.aes` in `guide_legend` to change the aesthetic settings in the legend without changing the plot.

```
+ guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "red")))
```

Comment: can you see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43286510/line-type-legend-not-showing-and-background-in-not-correct